# Unsigned Byte flip with *.bin file

Tags: vb.net

I need example in code, how to byte flip whole binary file. VB.NET

Example

```
02 00 0D 78 10 20 40 80 F1 F2 F4 F8 1F 2F 4F 8F
```

Flip Operation

```
00 02 78 0D 20 10 80 40 F2 F1 F8 F4 2F 1F 8F 4F
```

Whole, binary file using OpenFileDialog (OFD)

Comment: Are you having a particular problem or would you just like us to write the code for you?

Comment: yes :P xd Great site

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop all items of the array and swap each bytes.

```
Dim bytes() As Byte = {&H2, &H0, &HD, &H78, &H10, &H20, &H40, &H80, &HF1, &HF2, &HF4, &HF8, &H1F, &H2F, &H4F, &H8F}

For i As Integer = 0 To bytes.Length - 1 Step 2
    bytes(i) = bytes(i) Xor bytes(i + 1)
    bytes(i + 1) = bytes(i + 1) Xor bytes(i)
    bytes(i) = bytes(i) Xor bytes(i + 1)
Next
```

If you want, use a temp variable

```
For i As Integer = 0 To bytes.Length - 1 Step 2
    Dim tempByte As Byte = bytes(i)
    bytes(i) = bytes(i+1)
    bytes(i + 1) = tempByte
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

erm, you could write as you go, something like,

```
Dim file = dialog.FileName

Using output = New BinaryWriter(New FileStream( _
                   file, _
                   FileMode.Append, _
                   FileAccess.Write, _
                   FileShare.Read))
    Using input = New BinaryReader(New FileStream( _
                       file, _
                       FileMode.Open, _
                       FileAccess.Read, _
                       FileShare.ReadWrite))

        Dim bufferLength = 2
        While bufferLength = 2
            Dim buffer = input.ReadBytes(2)
            bufferLength = buffer.Length
            If bufferLength = 2 Then
                output.Write(buffer(1))
                output.Write(buffer(0))
            Else If bufferLength = 1 Then
                output.Write(buffer(0))
            End If
        End While

    End Using
End Using
```